# OpenLayers 3 Build from master

Tags: build, openlayers-3

I've cloned the [OpenLayers 3 repo](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3) and merged the latest from master.  There exists a recently merged pull request that I'm interested in exploring, but I'm not sure how to create a regular old comprehensive, non-minified build.

Does anyone know how to create a non-minified, kitchen sink (everything included) build for OpenLayers?

(similar to [ol-debug.js](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.0.0/build/ol-debug.js)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ol-debug.json` config](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.5.0/config/ol-debug.json) to concatenate all sources for the library without any minification.

```
node tasks/build.js config/ol-debug.json ol-debug.js
```

Where the `ol-debug.json` looks like this:

```json
{
  "exports": ["*"],
  "umd": true
}
```

The [`build.js` task](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.5.0/tasks/readme.md#buildjs) generates builds of the library given a JSON config files.  The [custom build](http://openlayers.org/en/v3.5.0/doc/tutorials/custom-builds.html) tutorial describes how this can be used to create minified profiles of the library.  For a debug build, you can simply omit the `compile` member of the build config.  This is described in the [task readme](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/blob/v3.5.0/tasks/readme.md#buildjs):

> If the **compile** object is not provided, the build task will generate a "debug" build of the library without any variable naming or other minification. This is suitable for development or debugging purposes, but should not be used in production.